# Ist "Wenn sie lügen sollten" grammatikalisch richtig?

Tags: grammaticality

Man kann entweder

> Wenn du lügst, verlierst du mein Vertrauen.

oder

> Solltest du lügen, verlierst du mein Vertrauen.

sagen.

Mehrmals habe ich jedoch folgenden Satz gelesen.

> Wenn du lügen solltest, verlierst du mein Vertrauen.

**Anmerkung:** Das ist nicht der originale Satz, sondern nur ein Beispiel.

Comment: Was veranlaßt dich zu glauben, es könnte nicht richtig sein?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Der Satz ist korrekt und enthält eine Warnung, mit der für den Fall, daß du lügst, etwas angedroht wird.